# MariaDB - Replication. Seconds_Behind_Master value increase after sometime

Tags: mariadb, replication

I have Master-Slave replication-enabled databases on separate servers.
Master - MariaDB 10.1.10
Slave - MariaDB 10.6.11
Initially slave database sync with the master. But after a few hours, `Seconds_Behind_Master` parameter getting increased. After restarting mariadb service issue fixed. But again after a few minutes issue occurred.
I have tested with changing `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` parameters to 0,1 and 2. But the issue still persists.

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
port = 3306
socket = /u01/mariadb/mysql/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]

datadir=/u01/mariadb/mysql
socket=/u01/mariadb/mysql/mysqld.sock

innodb_log_file_size = 512M

innodb_strict_mode = 0
lower_case_table_names          =  1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
skip-name-resolve

slave_run_triggers_for_rbr = ENFORCE
slave-run-triggers=yes

innodb_file_per_table = 1

default_storage_engine=InnoDB

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2


log-bin
server_id=10181117
log-basename=master
binlog-format=mixed
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
slave_run_triggers_for_rbr = ENFORCE

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I have tested with changing `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` parameters to 0,1 and 2. But the issue still persists.

Comment: [slave_parallel_threads](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#slave_parallel_threads) maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue sorted after downgrading to `10.5.15-MariaDB-1:10.5.15+maria~focal-log mariadb.org binary distribution`.